# Way to determine array that has most items?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array that has 4 arrays in it. What I need to do is take the one that has most numbers in it, if I have 2 or more arrays with same max numbers in it I will combine them.

Example array, we see that array `0` and `3` have max members that is `3`. So what I will do is take them and combine.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 9
        )
)
```

This is what I have, *it works* but I think it can be done better.

```
// Getting arrays that have most members in it
$max = count($groupArray[0]);
foreach ($groupArray as $group) {
    if (count($group) > $max) {
        $max = count($group);
    }
}

// Taking all those arrays and combining them in one
$finishArray = array();
foreach ($groupArray as $group) {
    if (count($group) == $max) {
        foreach ($group as $key) {
            array_push($finishArray, $key);
        }
    }
}
```

So can it be done better or this is how it should look like?

Comment: Instead of array_push'ing all the items in the array to the other array, you can use array_merge (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). That's the only thing I'd change at first glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it in one loop instead of two.

Instead of finding the max in one loop and searching for that max in a second loop, search while you are looping, and change the max if you find a bigger array and reset your result. You know there is no match before that point, so you can go on.

```
$max = 0;

foreach($groupArray as $arr) {
    $count = count($arr);
    if($count > $max) {
        $result = $arr;
        $max = $count;
    } else if($count == $max) {
        $result = array_merge($result, $arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd make one change here, he wants the final array to contain all the values, not the arrays of values.  So, I'd change `$result[] = $arr;` to `$result = array_merge($result, $arr);`

Comment: @marvin: I made it even better :-P (`$result = array();` isn't necessary anymore now that you have `$result = $arr`).

Answer (score 1):

What you have works, and I don't know how much it can be improved, but I'm gonna try.

To get the max count, you can do something like this (`array_map` is awesome):

```
$max = max(array_map(create_function('$a','return count($a);'), $groupArray));
```

If you have PHP 5.3, you can do this:

```
$max = max(array_map(function($a){return count($a);}, $groupArray));
```

As for the 2nd part, you're gonna have to loop though the array and get the arrays with the same length (like you did), but instead of looping though and using `array_push`, you could just use `array_merge`.

```
$finishArray = array();
foreach($groupArray as $group){
    if(count($group) === $max){
        $finishArray = array_merge($finishArray, $group);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through `$groupArray` twice, just store the indices of the longest children.

```
<?php

$indices = array();
$max_len = 0;

for ($i=0, $n=count($groupArray); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $tmp = count( $groupArray[$i] );
    if ( $tmp > $max_len ) {
        $max_len = $tmp;
        $indices = array($i);
    } elseif ( $tmp == $max_len ) {
        $indices[] = $i;
    }
}

$finishArray = array();
for ($i=0, $n=count($indices); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $finishArray = array_merge( $finishArray, $groupArray[ $indices[$i] ] );
}
```